# Yes/No Parameter in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to set a Parameter field for Yes/No based a value in MobileSetupMaster.VehicleType.

A Yes value would indicate MobileSetupMaster.VehicleType = '1614' while a No would include all values <> '1614'.

Would a new Formula Field be the best way to handle this?  And if so, how should it look?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Create a `booleanvar` parameter field.

Add the following to record-selection formula:

```
If {?BooleanParameter}=True Then
  {MobileSetupMaster.VehicleType} = '1614'
Else
  {MobileSetupMaster.VehicleType} <> '1614'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think it is almost there.  What I did was create a parameter called "MAPH" and made it Boolean.  Then I created a Formula and named it "MAPHForm" with your If/Else statement:If {?MAPH}=True Then
  totext({rpt_MobileSetupMaster.VehicleType}) = '1614'
Else
  totext({rpt_MobileSetupMaster.VehicleType}) <> '1614'.  I then included in the Record Selection {@MAPHForm}. But when I run the report and look at the SQL code generated, it is not including in the WHERE clause the rpt_MobileSetupMaster.Vehicle = '1614'.  Thoughts?